# libapache2-mod-auth-pgsql and ssl-cert equivalent in CentOS

Tags: authentication, postgresql, ssl-certificate, httpd, centos6

I switched this a time ago from Ubuntu to CentOS. Now, I faced this problem:

Trying to install a software that I installed before in Ubuntu, I stopped at the point where I need to install the above mentioned modules: `libapache2-mod-auth-pgsql` and `ssl-cert`. Can anybody tell me how to install them in CentOS, or some equivalent libraries to them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one:

```
$ yum search mod_auth_pgsql
======================================================== N/S Matched: mod_auth_pgsql =========================================================
mod_auth_pgsql.i686 : Basic authentication for the Apache HTTP Server using a PostgreSQL database
```

The `ssl-cert` package is a Debian shell script wrapping openssl to make things easier, or something like that.  I don't believe there's an equivalent.  On the other hand, it's just a shell script plus some config files.  You should be able to just grab that, and, in the worst case, figure out how to run `openssl` with the right options.

Also, if you're just generated SSL certs to use with Postgres, you can look for explicit instructions on using `openssl`.  For example:

http://www.howtoforge.com/postgresql-ssl-certificates